# Massive growth in binary logs over past few days with no change in behaviour

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We're experiencing disk size growth from 272 GB to 3.4 TB (and still growing). We tracked this down to growth in binary logs. Checking a recent backup, we used to have 3 binary log files, now we have 1200. We have had no change in our application usage that we can think that can account for this (and this shows in our read/write graphs, for example)

Has anyone seen this issue, or can provide more info for how we can debug whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

GCP Support here,

It seems that this issue has to be further investigated, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/), please create a new case.

Otherwise, you can open a new issue on our [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). As you will have to share your project ID, open it using [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274&template=1161130). This will create a private thread, so it will be visible only for you and the support team.

Comment: Thank you! Just to note that I got in contact with GCP support and they are dealing with the issue there. Thanks again for your help!